# FluentValidation error grouping for complex properties

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I have a problem figuring out how to override the 'flat' error formatting like following:

```
{
    "Discount": [
        "'Discount' must be greater than or equal to '0'."
    ],
    "Guest.LastName": [
        "'Last Name' should not be empty."
    ],
    "Guest.CountryId": [
        "'Country Id' should not be empty."
    ],
    "Guest.FirstName": [
        "'First Name' should not be empty."
    ],
    "Guest.DocumentTypeId": [
        "'Document Type Id' should not be empty."
    ]
}
```

into something like:

```
{
    "Discount": [
        "'Discount' must be greater than or equal to '0'."
    ],
    "Guest": [
        //grouped errors
    ]
}
```

I am not doing anything fancy, merely calling:

```
RuleFor(m => m.Guest).SetValidator(new CheckInGuestModelValidator())
```

Is it even possible to obtain the resulting errors as non-flat list?

Thank you
Piotr